# Regex pattern for containing string as well as not ending with pattern

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I have been asked to make 2 regex to determine by the URL if a page is a product page or a category page.

These are the URLs:

Product page: `www.domain.com/art/something/someotherthing/article(X123456.123)/`

Category page: `www.domain.com/art/something/someotherthing`

I created this regex which works fine for the product page:

```
^.*\/art.*\/[xX]?[0-9]{6,7}\.[0-9]+\/$
```

Now I have problems with the category page. The only thing I see that is possible is to make sure it does not end with the pattern that check the ending numbers "[xX]?[0-9]{6,7}.[0-9]+". But I also need to make sure that it starts with /art/ after the domain.

My first try was this for the category page:

```
.*\/art.*\/(?!([xX]?[0-9]{6,7}\.[0-9]+\(\/)?))$
```

This doesn't work since negative lookup is positive since it does not find the pattern after the 2nd any characters matching (`.*`).

Comment: Neither regex matches the product page. What are the specifications? Try [`^.*\/art.*[xX]?[0-9]{6,7}\.[0-9]+\)\/$`](https://regex101.com/r/sE7lL1/1) and [`^.*\/art\/(?!.*[xX]?[0-9]{6,7}\.[0-9]+\)\/$).*$`](https://regex101.com/r/sE7lL1/2).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a differencing factor is the number of slashes, possibly excluded by an optional end-slash that is often ignored.

```
^[^\/]*(\/[^\/]*){3}\/?$    would match the category, and
^[^\/]*(\/[^\/]*){4}\/?$    would match the product.
```

Comment: Technically `^.*/.*/.*/.*/?$` can also match anything with 3 or more slashes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have to use any lookarounds here.

Since the `domain` is permanent and the `art` is permanent and the last part of the product like `article+something` is permanent you can use them explicitly in the regex making it faster.

For product:

```
^www\.domain\.com\/art\/[^\/]+\/[^\/]+\/article\([^\/]+\)\/$
```

For category:

```
^www\.domain\.com\/art\/[^\/]+\/[^\/]+\/$
```

Answer (score 0):

From the question description and the URL data given...

1. Product URLs

   - matched by [`^([^\/\r\n]+?)\/(art)\/(.*)\/.*?\(([xX]?[0-9]{6,7}\.[0-9]+)\).*?\/?$`](https://regex101.com/r/rN6aJ0/4)
   - 1st capture == domain
   - 2nd capture == art (main category?)
   - 3rd capture == category
   - 4th capture == Product ID
2. Category URLs

   - matched by [`^([^\/\r\n]+?)\/(art)\/((?!.*[xX]?[0-9]{6,7}\.[0-9]+).*?)\/?$`](https://regex101.com/r/rN6aJ0/5)
   - 1st capture == domain
   - 2nd capture == art (main category?)
   - 3rd capture == category

I did infer that the trailing `/` was optional for both URLs, but that may be an incorrect assumption.

The above regex's link to live regex101 fiddlers with the given regex plus test data.

Do note that the `\r\n` inclusion within the character class for the domain match is only needed because the regex101 fiddler match is done globally on combined test data. You can remove that character sequence if you are only matching against a single URL at a time.